# pagination in Listview of android using Base adapter?

Tags: android, android-widget

i use the base adapter to fill the list view with the dat fetched from SQL lite . My actual requirement  is to show only 10 row in a list view , when i click next ,the set of next 10 data from local database need to fetched and update the current list View. but i don`t know how to implement this.

anyone provide some sample code or solution to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to send the adapter only a subset of the entire data ( in your case 10 elements) . When the next button is pressed , you can send the adapter the next 10 set of elements and then call notifyDataSetChanged on it to update the listview.

Comment: i don`t want to update it , i want to clear and reload the listview

Comment: If you change the data the adapter is displaying and call notifyDataSetChanged , its the same thing and a clear and reload